# Python & BeautifulSoup : How to extract a tags' value which is in many others tags?

Tags: python, css, beautifulsoup

```
<a href="link" target="_blank" class="xXx text-user topic-author" sl-processed="1">
    diamonds
</a>
```

I would like to extract the pseudo 'diamonds' which is in the 'a' tag with BeautifulSoup.

I tried a lot of things but it always return me 'None'.

For me the thing which was supposed to work was this

```
 txt = soup.find('a', {'class': 'xXx text-user topic-author'})
 print (txt)
```

Comment: please share what you've tried.

Comment: @eLRuLL Sry, I've edited !

Comment: You're inrerested in the word diamonds?

Comment: @jlaur Yes I am.

Comment: Load the html into an object named soup. a = soup.a. diamonds = a.text.strip()

Comment: @jlaur Can you make a post please ? I don't really understand your answer. And I didn't noticed it but the diamonds will change (I had to use soup.find_all)

Comment: Post the code you've tried that return None and I'll tell you where you took the wrong turn...

Comment: @jlaur I have edited my first post !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the css classes for the authors aren't the same through out the page, so you need to do some filtering.

The author elements have multiple css classes, but they share some similarities.

The code below will print out the authors. It first grabs the elements where the authors will be. The problem is that this css-class (JvCare) is used for many things. An elements count returns 98 for the page, but there are only 25 author names, so a little filtering is needed afterwards.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.jeuxvideo.com/forums/0-7059-0-1-0-1-0-another-war.htm"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
JvCs = soup.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'JvCare'})
for j in JvCs:
    if 'topic-author' in j['class']:
        print(j.text.strip())
```

j['class'] returns a list of the different css-classes for each of the 98 elements in the JvCs-list. The ones where the author name resides, has a css-class named 'topic-author'.

So we just check if 'topic-author' is in the list returned by j['class'] for each of the 98 elements. If so - print the author name.

Hope this helps you get further.

**Edit:**
It seems there's a smarter way of doing this (mentioned in the really awesome [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for BeautifulSoup) for situations where there are two or more css selectors involved. In these cases the docs recommends using the .select-method. In your case that would be like so:

```
author_list = soup.select('span.JvCare.topic-author')
for author in author_list:
    print(author.text.strip())
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. I've put the author into a list. I'm sure that your post will help me for other css "selector" if we can call it like that. Thanks a lot.